# routing errors while changing into production mode in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

Hey, I hope you can help me. Ive been working in development mode all the time.
Everything seems fine so far.  As I started up the production mode all my .css and .js got routing errors and were not visible.

Many thanks!

`Started GET "/javascripts/application.js?1293486752" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Jan 13 23:11:21 +0100 2011`

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/javascripts/application.js"):`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails defaults to not serving static assets in production, as the web server is generally more optimized for those kind of tasks. Most likely this is the problem.

To fix it, you can either set `config.serve_static_assets = true` in `config/environments/production.rb`, or configure the web server to do it for you.

Comment: hey thx but it didnt change. I added it and restarted the server

Comment: what server are you using to run the app? and dumb question, but you do have an javascripts/application.js with some content?

Comment: your answer makes sense. Later ago I uploaded to heroku and the css/javascripts were running fine. But It wouldnt let me sign up (devise). I got errors. Thats why I wanted to check the production mode, but here all functions are fine except the stylesheets.